# A bob being at equilibrium at every position

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, harmonic-oscillator

In this [video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=e9yJPdbLhEI&feature=share), at 1:39 it had been said that the bob is at equilibrium at every position of the path it traverses and therefore balanced the forces? It didn't make any sense to me. How can it be at equilibrium at all the positions of it's path? How are they even able to balance the forces?

Answer (score 2):

There is an assumption that the applied horizontal force $\vec F$ moves the pendulum bob *very slowly* so that the bob can be treated as being in equilibrium at all times. This assumption is stated at 0:25 in the video.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,in the video the forces when resolved vertically gave birth to the equation $mg=T\cos theta$ and so on. Why didn't we take centripetal force into consideration while resolving the forces?Is there any particular reason for which we can neglect centripetal force in this case and just use tension?

Comment: @madness There is no need to think about centripetal force because the pendulum bob is *not moving* (in fact, it is best not to think of it as a pendulum at all). We assume the applied force is moving the bob very slowly, and so we treat the bob as if it were stationary (and so in equilibrium) at each point in time. No swinging to and fro, so no centripetal force.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation,a last question,what role does $T$ play here?I mean what would have happened if $T$ didn't act?

Answer (score 1):

If the bob were swinging, the only equilibrium point would be at the bottom of the swing where the acceleration is zero. In this video, the bob is held nearly stationary at each angle θ by the external force F.